SQL statement to select a customer record and every phone number associated with it
I have a Customers table and a CustomerPhones table. The Customers table has columns ID, FirstName, Lastname. The phone numbers table has CustomerID, PhoneNumber, PhoneType.
Let's say I have the following data in the Customers table:
ID   Firstname  Lastname
------------------------
1    Bob        Smith

And then in the phone numbers table
Customerid   PhoneNumber     PhoneType
--------------------------------------
    1        111111111          H
    1        222222222          C
    1        333333333          C

If I use the simple JOIN SQL, I will get 3 rows:
SELECT
    c.id, c.FirstName, c.LastName, P.PhoneNumber, P.Phonetype 
FROM
    Customers c
JOIN
    CustomerPhoneNumbers P ON p.customerid = c.id

Results:
ID   Firstname   Lastname   phonenumber    phonetype
--------------------------------------------------
1    Bob         Smith      111111111       H
1    Bob         Smith      222222222       C
1    Bob         Smith      333333333       C

How do I turn that into results with 1 row but with each number?
ID  Firstname   Lastname    phonenumber phonetype   phonenumber phonetype   phonenumber phonetype
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       Bob         Smith       111111111   H             222222222 C           333333333   C

Could it be dynamic, since customers can have any number of phone numbers? Thank you for the time and help.

The SQL language has a strict rule: you MUST know the number of columns at query compile time, before looking at ANY data.
Therefore this will not be possible in a single query if you can have an arbitrary number of phone numbers for a person, because you have to look at the data to know how many columns you need.
Instead, the best option is to PIVOT the data in the client code or reporting tool.
The alternatives:

Using STRING_AGG() or similar to roll up the phone numbers into a single column

Limiting to the first reasonable N phone numbers. This can work, but it requires a separate manual JOIN to the phone table for each additional number and manually specifying the column... that is, it's awkward to build and slow to run.

Showing all phones numbers in their own column, as requested, by using three separate steps: First, run a query to find out how many phone number columns you need. Second, use the results from the first step to build a new query on the fly (using the slow and awkward multiple join technique from the previous option). Finally, run the query.



You want to pivot your data. For that, you first need some sequence number, by which you determine which of the (maximum three, in my example) children goes where.
Therefore, after beefing up your data to show two customers, one with two and one with your three phone numbers,

I create a sub-select - a Common Table Expression in a WITH clause - to add a sequence number to your phone number's table, and name it w_seq
then I join w_seq and customer, and pivot so that the phone numbers' columns are displayed across, using a MAX(CASE seq WHEN n THEN phoneno END) AS phoneno_n aggregate expression, for example, and finally group by id, first name and last name.

WITH
-- input data ...
customers(c_id,fname,lname) AS (
            SELECT 1,'Bob','Smith'
  UNION ALL SELECT 2,'Joe','Baker'
)
,
custphones(c_id,phoneno,phonetp) AS (
            SELECT 1,111111111,'H'
  UNION ALL SELECT 1,222222222,'C'
  UNION ALL SELECT 1,333333333,'C'
  UNION ALL SELECT 2,222222222,'M'
  UNION ALL SELECT 2,333333333,'W'
)
-- end of input data, real query starts here
-- replace following comma with "WITH" ...                                                                                                                 
,
w_seq AS (
  SELECT
    c_id
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c_id) AS seq
  , phoneno
  , phonetp
  FROM custphones
)
SELECT
  c.c_id
, fname
, lname
, MAX(CASE seq WHEN 1 THEN phoneno END) AS phoneno_1
, MAX(CASE seq WHEN 1 THEN phonetp END) AS phonetp_1
, MAX(CASE seq WHEN 2 THEN phoneno END) AS phoneno_2
, MAX(CASE seq WHEN 2 THEN phonetp END) AS phonetp_2
, MAX(CASE seq WHEN 3 THEN phoneno END) AS phoneno_3
, MAX(CASE seq WHEN 3 THEN phonetp END) AS phonetp_3
FROM customers c
JOIN w_seq USING(c_id)
GROUP BY
  c.c_id
, fname
, lname
;




c_id
fname
lname
phoneno_1
phonetp_1
phoneno_2
phonetp_2
phoneno_3
phonetp_3




1
Bob
Smith
111111111
H
222222222
C
333333333
C


2
Joe
Baker
222222222
M
333333333
W
(null)
(null)




Thank you so much, I was able to get this to work. I had to add an Order By in the Over clause. But without your help, I would not have gotten here. Thank you again.
